# Javascript pass by reference and props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, react-props

As I understand correctly in Javascript we have two different passing: by value and by reference. By value is when we pass the strings or numbers. By reference when we pass the objects or arrays.

Last time in some project I noticed antipattern -> someone assigned new value to `this.props.arrayOfNames = newArrayOfNames;`

I haven't had the chance to test it, but... will it change somehow the parent's object? By reference?

Answer (score 5):

`this.props.arrayOfNames = newArrayOfNames` is not an antipattern but a mistake. `props` object is immutable, this is ensured by the use of `Object.freeze` in development mode. The assignment of `arrayOfNames` property value will result in error.

If props should differ from received ones, a correct way is to use a state that derives from props with `getDerivedStateFromProps` hook.